# Cartopy version of NaturalEarth porting error

Tags: python, maps, cartopy, rnaturalearth

The code below gives me an error telling me:

```
File "/home/ludo915/Eco-Tech H2GAM/maps.py", line 242, in compute_maps
    a.add_geometries(countryEU['F'].polygon, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
TypeError: 'NaturalEarth_v5_0_0' object is not subscriptable
```

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
            gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 1)
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            axes = [ax1]
            ax1.background_patch.set_fill(False)
            for a in axes:
                a.add_geometries(countryEU['F'].polygon, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor=grayDark, lw=2, facecolor=grayDark, alpha=0.6, zorder=0)
                a.set_extent([-5,10,41,52])
                a.set_aspect('auto')
                a.outline_patch.set_linewidth(0.)
                pass
```

My script worked perfectly before the migration to `V5_0_0` of `NaturalEarth`. Any ideas?

Post transferred to https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/issues/884

Asked for an update on stackoverflow.

This works now but the greyscale enlightenin foreground no longer fits the map correctly any ideas?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
            gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 1)
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            axes = [ax1]
            ax1.background_patch.set_fill(False)
            for a in axes:
                a.add_geometries([regionmask.defined_regions.prudence["FR"].polygon,], ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor=grayDark, lw=2, facecolor=grayDark, alpha=0.6, zorder=0)
                a.set_extent([-5,10,41,52])
                a.set_aspect('auto')
                a.outline_patch.set_linewidth(0.)
                pass

            cax = ax1.scatter(risk1Maps[counter].lon,risk1Maps[counter].lat,c=risk1Maps[counter].idx,
            cmap='RdYlGn_r', s=markersize*5, vmin=0, vmax=risk1max, zorder=4)
            cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, orientation='horizontal', pad=0, aspect=50,
            fraction=.01, extend='max', drawedges=False, ticks=[0, risk1max])
            cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(['low', 'high'])
            cbar.ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
            cbar.ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')

            ax1.text(0,.0,'Data \nCAMS \ndata.gouv.fr', transform=ax1.transAxes,fontdict={'size':12})

            currentDateWD = today.strftime('%a, %d - %m, %Y')
            ax1.set_title('PM2.5 concentrations: \n{:}\n'.format(currentDateWD + " + "+ str (counter) + " days"),
            loc='left', pad=-60)

            fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=.01, left=.01, right=.99, top=.99)
            #plt.show()
            buffer = io.BytesIO()
            plt.savefig(buffer, format='png', dpi=70)
            buffer.seek(0)
            images1.append(imageio.imread(buffer))
            buffer.close()
            plt.close()
```

[image: SO2 Forecasts]

Ludo

Comment: Try changing "countryEU['F'].polygon" to "[countryEU['F'].polygon, ]"

Comment: maybe they changed some functions in new version.

Comment: Right ty I solved the issue by using a.add_geometries([regionmask.defined_regions.prudence["FR"].polygon,], ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                edgecolor=grayDark, lw=2, facecolor=grayDark, alpha=0.6, zorder=0)

Comment: But I have a new issue w greyscale enlightenin foreground